# Lucene ClassNotFoundError when loading analyzer

Tags: java, lucene

I tried to run Lucene Indexer but it gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
Exception in thread "main"
```

I used compile command:

```
 javac -classpath 'C:/Users/Daniel/desktop/Java WorkSpace/JavaPackage/lucene-3.0.0/lucene-core-3.0.0.jar' Indexer.java;
```

and it works.

But when I tried to execute the compiled class:

```
java Indexer;
```

It gives me the ClassNotFoundException().  PS: the compiled class file and jar file are not in the same folder. Would that matter?

Thanks!

Comment: Add the classpath argument also to the java call.

Comment: Adding the classpath argument seems to cause no main method found error

Comment: And that simply means that you have no main method (in your Indexer class).

Comment: Here is the code:  java -cp 'C:/users/daniel/desktop/study/fall 2014/text analytics/assignment3/lucene-core-3.0.0.jar' Indexer

Comment: I have static void main defined in that class. But it still gives no 'could not find or load main class Indexer'

Comment: You should open another question (as the missing main method is another problem) and post the relevant code. Otherwise no one can help you!

Answer (score 0):

The Lucene Analyzers are no longer in the Lucene core. Download the JAR (or add to your Maven dependencies) for the corresponding version here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers